# Pygame, unselecting character

Tags: python, pygame

First of all maybe two short information: I am literally programming since only seven days and my English is not exactly perfect, so please keep that in mind :).

So, what do I want this program to do:
If I click on the character (here a green square) I want him to become selected. After that the next click will move it to this position and the character is not selected anymore. If I want to move him to a new position, he needs again to be selected first.

What it does:
Well, it works for the most part but once in a while (I guess like one in ten times) I will be able to move the character twice instead of just once. Can someone tell me why?

The code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

MAP_WIDTH=20
MAP_HEIGHT=20

TILESIZE=40

clickAt=(None,None)
justClicked=False
newPos=False

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURFACE=pygame.display.set_mode((MAP_WIDTH*TILESIZE,MAP_HEIGHT*TILESIZE))

###############################

class Character:

    def __init__(self, name, x, y, texture):

        self.name=name
        self.x=x//40
        self.y=y//40
        self.texture=texture
        self.selected=False

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURFACE, (0, 0, 0), (self.x*TILESIZE,self.y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

        if self.selected==True:
            self.x=clickAt[0]//40
            self.y=clickAt[1]//40
            self.selected=False

        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURFACE, (0, 255, 0), (self.x*TILESIZE,self.y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))


Mustermann=Character('Frodo', 33, 79, 'test')

Characters=[Mustermann]

##################################

while True:

    #checking the events#
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print ("mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
            clickAt=event.pos
            justClicked=True

    #render characters#
    for char in Characters:

        #check if character is about to be placed on a new position
        if clickAt[0]!=None and (clickAt[0]//40)!=char.x and (clickAt[1]//40)!=char.y:
            newPos=True

        char.draw()

        #if placed on a new position let char.seletcted in False until character is clicked on again
        if newPos==True:
            newPos=False
            justClicked=False


    #check if klicked on character#
    for char in Characters:
        if clickAt[0]!=None and justClicked==True and (clickAt[0]//40)==char.x and (clickAt[1]//40)==char.y:
            char.selected=True


    pygame.display.update()
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the following check:

```
if clickAt[0] != None and (clickAt[0]//40) != char.x and (clickAt[1]//40) != char.y:
```

Assuming that `clickAt[0] != None` is true, the following check is made:

```
clickAt[0] != char.x and clickAt[1] != char.y
```

So in order to make the condition true, *both* the X and the Y positions of your click need to be different from the original location. This allows for the following effect:

[image: example scenario]

So basically, as long as either the X or the Y position stays the same, you can move the character as often as you want. And you don’t need to always change only the X or the Y position either, you can switch between each click.

To fix this, you have to adjust the check to check for *any* position change:

```
(clickAt[0] != char.x or clickAt[1] != char.y)
```

This is also the actual inverse of the check you do later (check [De Morgan’s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)):

```
(clickAt[0]//40) == char.x and (clickAt[1]//40) == char.y
```

So your full condition is this:

```
if clickAt[0] is not None and ((clickAt[0]//40) != char.x or (clickAt[1]//40) != char.y):
    newPos = True
```

Comment: Thanks! That was very fast and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the fact that you call the char.draw() method (which changes the square's position) before you actually set the Character's selected member to True.